# Duplicate code detection: Tools you can use

Tags: javascript, duplicates, dry, code-duplication

I am looking out for a software that identifies duplicate/redundant Javascript code. I found one such tool named [CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone), but don't know how good it is .

I was looking out for similar open source tools . Please guide .

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what duplicate code means, but Google's Closure Compiler will compress your code and strip out any which is unused.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of the following stackoverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546487/tools-to-identify-code-duplications

Answer (score 1):

I used [PMD's Copy/Paste Detector (CPD)](https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_cpd.html) last year on a project.  There was some code for [EcmascriptLanguage](http://pmd.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pmd/trunk/pmd/src/net/sourceforge/pmd/cpd/EcmascriptLanguage.java?view=log) support but I recall having to update [GUI.java](http://pmd.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pmd/trunk/pmd/src/net/sourceforge/pmd/cpd/GUI.java?revision=6353&view=markup) and recompile the project to get it to work.

Comment: The link for PMD no longer works, moved from sourceforge to github it seems, updating with new link: https://pmd.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

If you use ruby (or even have it on your system) you may want to try [flay-js](https://rubygems.org/gems/flay-js) ([flay](https://rubygems.org/gems/flay) plugin)

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth checking out the coverage section in Google Chrome, relatively new feature: 
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#coverage

> Find unused CSS and JS code with the new Coverage tab. When you load or run a page, the tab tells you how much code was used, versus how much was loaded. You can reduce the size of your pages by only shipping the code that you need.

Comment: Really interesting, but it will find dead code not duplicate code.